# Data connection to webservice works after being edited but fails after closing and reopening Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've created an Excel workbook that retrieves data from a REST webservice. Works perfectly on my machine. But if the end user opens the sheet and clicks "Daten/Alle aktualisieren" ("Data/Refresh all" or the like, sorry our Excel is German) he gets the error (instantly, without even contacting the server):

> Initialisierung der Datenquelle schlug fehl.
> Überprüfen Sie den Datenbankserver oder kontaktieren Sie Ihren Datenbankadministrator. Vergewissern Sie sich, dass die externe Datenbank verfügbar ist, und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang. Sofern diese Nachricht wiede erscheint, erstellen Sie eine neue Datenquelle um mit der Datenbank Verbindung aufzunehmen

Must be something like

> Initialization of datasource failed
> Check the database server or contact your database administrator. Make sure the external database is available. ...

Now the user clicks "Daten/Abfragen anzeigen" ("Data/show queries"), opens the query in editor and clicks "Schließen & laden" ("Close & load") and everything works fine! He can refresh the data with "Alle aktualisieren". But after saving the workbook, closing Excel and reopening it he again gets the error. 
The user and I both work with Excel 2016. Did anyone see this issue before? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It can be a config or security issue on his machine (check Excel options), it can be that he can't contact the machine with the service due to a firewall or network issue (try pinging from his machine or accessing the service directly via Telnet or Browser), it may be that he doesn't have the proper drivers (or extra software) installed on his machine (check software requisites), perhaps you connect via DSN and he doesn't have it configured (configure DSN on Windows). Other issues may also be in effect (check Windows Event Log).

Comment: Guessing here. It may be that the connection is saved as a local connection file on the users computer. This file does not travel with the workbook or even stays in the same folder. However because of user rights, Excel is unable to save the connection file to the local folder. Close and load temporarily creates the connection file but is unable to save it or utilise it beyond one session.